# HikariPoolMXBean - getThreadsAwaitingConnection - what do threads refer to?

Tags: threadpool, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I'm trying to use the HikariPoolMXBean to gather connection pool metrics and want to be clear on what one of the metrics means:

```
/**
    * Get the number of threads awaiting connections from the pool.  The return value is extremely transient and is
    * a point-in-time measurement.
    *
    * @return the number of threads awaiting a connection from the pool
    */
   int getThreadsAwaitingConnection();
```

In the context of this metric, what is a thread? Is it an application thread, database thread, or something else? Is it a thread used internally by HikariCP?

Answer (score 0):

Threads in [HikariPoolMXBean](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/3.1.0/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariPoolMXBean.html#getThreadsAwaitingConnection--) are related to your application threads waiting to get connection from pool

> threads calling DataSource.getConnection()